# TouchEvents on Canvas in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mvvm

I'm currently trying to implement a ImageViewer with the possibility to move and zoom with touch inputs. 
I already implemented these functionalities in a recent project in the Code Behind, but I'm struggling to do so in a View Model in MVVM.

Problem is that for my code to work I have to know how many touch inputs are recognized at the same time. 
In my Code-Behind I used:

```
canvas.TouchesCaptured.Count()
```

The ViewModel shouldn't not know any Controls of the View, so passing the Canvas as a Command Parameter is not the way to go.

Beside the canvas I need the TouchEventArgs of the triggered TouchEvent to determine the position of the TouchEvent on the canvas.
Using Prism I was able to get the TouchEventArgs into the ViewModel.

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TouchDown">
            <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TouchDownCommand}"
        </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

prism:InvokeCommandAction automatically sets the EventArgs as the CommandParameter for clarification.

To determine the position of the TouchEvent on the Canvas I need the canvas and the TouchEvent.
In my Code-Behind it looked like that:

```
startingPoint = e.GetTouchPoint(canvas);
```

Anyone has a idea how I can solve this problem without violating the MVVM Pattern?

Comment: For "move and zoom with touch inputs" take a look at the manipulation events, like [ManipulationDelta](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationdelta(v=vs.110).aspx) etc. See also [Touch and Manipulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/input-overview#touch-and-manipulation).

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing a Blend behavior that encapsulates the Canvas event handling and exposes commands (e.g. ManipulationDelta in particular). You could even add a property to the behavior that exposes the TouchesCaptured values (during the ManipulationDelta event).

e.g.

```
<Canvas>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <bhv:CanvasBehavior ManipulationDeltaCommand="{Binding MyViewModelCommand}" TouchPointCount="{Binding MyViewModelTouchPointCount}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Canvas>
```